# hiredis install rebuild fail

Tags: npm, rebuild, hiredis

I'm trying to install hiredis through npm on a mac and I am getting this error. I know there are some possible duplicates of this but I've tried other solutions and they have not worked for me. Here is the log:

```
11 warnings and 17 errors generated.
make: *** [Release/obj.target/hiredis/src/hiredis.o] Error 1
gyp ERR! build error
gyp ERR! stack Error: `make` failed with exit code: 2
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/build.js:258:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:191:7)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:215:12)
gyp ERR! System Darwin 16.7.0
gyp ERR! command "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd /Users/Aric/myApp/node_modules/hiredis
gyp ERR! node -v v6.10.1
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.6.2
gyp ERR! not ok

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! hiredis@0.3.0 install: `node-gyp rebuild`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the hiredis@0.3.0 install script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe not the correct way to fix my problem but I upgraded hiredis to v0.5.0 from v0.3.0 and it solved the issue for me.